# Need Windows 7 (x86) Drivers for ATI Radeon 7500, do they exist?

Tags: windows-7, video, drivers, thinkpad, amd-radeon

I just repaved my ThinkPad A31 (vintage 2003) to 32-bit Windows 7.
This laptop has ATI Radeon 7500 video, and I've looked in the usual places.
It appears there isn't a driver for this.  Does anyone know of an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw a post on Seven Forums by "Shadowempire" that had the following information:

> Download The Vista Driver With OpenGl...

The general consensus of the posts seems to be that you need to install the Vista drivers.

**NOTE**

I've removed the links as the OP indicated that they pointed to dodgy sites. If you need the information either do the search yourself or check out the edit history.

Comment: I did follow the thread, and installed some stuff from that thread - one of the links lead to download that also popped up pron on my box, and set off Norton AV warnings - I repaved, and tried again with another source to install the Vista drivers, and my machine became unstable - thus I decided to use the default windows VGA driver and sacrifice higher resolution.

Comment: @ChrisF: I found the same thread you refer to {see above} ... but this laptop was stolen from my rental car while I was away last week, therefore, I no longer need the drivers.

Comment: @ChrisF: I voted you up for your efforts, but I am reluctant to mark this as the answer, because of the links in the post point to questionable sources (pron popups, etc.).  Hope that's not too much of a dis.

Comment: @James - no problem. I must admit that I didn't follow the links fully, I thought the point about the Vista drivers was the most important piece of information. I'll actually remove the the links so we're not pointing at dodgy sites.